# Probability Distribution for a Weird Card Game

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I promise this is not for a homework problem, even though this sounds like only something a professor would dream up. Here is the game:

I begin with a deck of 13 cards: 1 through 10, Jack, Queen, and King. My score begins at zero. To add to my score, I draw a card. If the card is 1 through 10, I add that number to my score. If I draw a face card, I add $X$ to my score and draw again.

The four questions I set out to answer were “How do I figure out what happens to the distribution of outcomes if…”

1) The value of $X$ increases or decreases?
2) When a face card is drawn, it is removed from the deck for the subsequent draw or draws?
3) The value of $X$ depends on the specific face card (e.g. $Jack = X$, $Queen = X+1$, $King =X+3$)?
4) The value of $X$ varies depending on how many face cards have been drawn (e.g. 1st $= X$, 2nd $= 2X$, 3rd $= 3X$)

I’ve managed to solve 1 & 2, but I am stuck on 3 & 4. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: (1) You misspelled "weird". (2) In your first sentence you insult half the people who answer questions here with your snotty crack about professors. (3) What's your motivation? Did you dream it up? Why are you interested? Why should we be interested? (4) Showing your work always helps. You say you managed to solve 1 & 2, so what are the answers to 1 & 2 and how did you get them? If I manage to solve 3 & 4, should I post an "answer" just saying that I solved them and not telling you anything else?

Comment: What is the value of X? How I can know if it increases or decreases if isnt defined? It is like if I ask to you how evolve the value of Z.

Comment: 1)It was 4:30 am and I missed the red squiggle, my bad.
2)It wasn't intended to be snotty, this is my first time using this site and I didn't want to come off as lazy.
3) My motivation is to solve a problem for a friend of mine who is attempting to convert a dice based system into a card based system for an RPG.
4) My work: In the "Troll" language on troll dice [link]http://topps.diku.dk/torbenm/troll.msp[/link]

function Cards(FACECARDS) = X:= d (10+FACECARDS);
if X > 10 then 2+ call Cards(FACECARDS-1) else X

call Cards(3)




call Cards(3)